# Java Spark and Jetty User Defined Config file and parameters

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I'm trying to figure out how I can set up a config file for Java Spark (the microframework) and its implementation of Jetty.

I've managed to deploy the full application as a single .jar file with its dependencies and I quite like that option, but if I do that I'm not sure how I can set up an external config file that can both help to configure Jetty but also have some user defined parameters for the running of other parts of the application.

I don't want these config options to be in the code, but rather a JSON, YAML, XML, etc... configuration properties file

Is it possible given the way I'm deploying it?

I've read that I simply need to edit `start.ini` and create a `/resources/myconfig.properties` file, though given my deployment method I don't believe it will work like that.